# How to make a linux VM Instance on GCP of more than 2TB. I am trying to Download a 2.4 TB file,

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Is it possible to make one drive on a GCP VM instance that has more than 2TB storage. I have a 2.5 TB file that I need to get into the VM instance but if I set the size to 4 TB I still get only 2 TB in my command line.

[image of output to df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxKWt.png)

Comment: This probably isn't the best site to ask this question, since it's primarily relating to server administration and not programming. Try [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). That being said, your issue is probably that you're using [EXT4](https://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4) as your file system on your volume. Try formatting the storage with something like ZFS instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only see 2 TB even though you created a 4 TB disk is because the disks use MBR as default, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd).

If you would like to change the disk from using MBR to GPT which will allow you to use the full volume size of your disk, you will need to download a third party tool to help with the conversion.

You can search online for different tools that will convert the disk such as gptgen for Windows or gdisk for Linux; however, there is the possibility some data may get corrupted.